MAUI Shell navigation crash (randomly?) (Windows)
I created a simple MAUI project to troubleshoot built-in MAUI AppShell navigation.
I have a MainPage (binded to a MainPageViewModel) with a CollectionView of ItemViewModel.
I have added in XAML a Gesture behavior to respond to double tapping on each of presented ItemViewModel, that will trigger a navigation to my second page : SelectPage.
I have done the routing of the navigation in a relative way so I can go back with the built-in go back button in navigation bar.
I test this navigation from going back and forth between my 2 pages, until it break out with a Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.NavigationFailed was unhandled. unhandled exception in App.g.I.cs generated file.
It can happen in either way of navigation (either going to my second page or going back to my main page).
This exception occur after a while but with no special pattern (could be the 5th times or the 13th times of navigation e.g.).
(NOTE that when using ScreenToGif to record this issue on video, so far it always crash on the second navigation ?!)
The second debugger break in App.g.i.cs is about System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException exception before closing app.
Here is my simple project on GitHub for code review.
And here is my video to illustrate this issue
The stack trace showed in the end is :
at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|38_0(Int32 hr)
at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.IFrameMethods.Navigate(IObjectReference _obj, Type sourcePageType, Object parameter, NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride)
at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.StackNavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationRequest args)
at Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper.InvokeCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView, Object args)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.SyncNavigationStack(Boolean animated, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.OnNavigationRequested(Object sender, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.InvokeNavigationRequest(NavigationRequestedEventArgs args)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.OnPushAsync(Page page, Boolean animated)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.PushStackOfPages(List`1 pages, Nullable`1 animate)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationRequest request, ShellRouteParameters queryData, IServiceProvider services, Nullable`1 animate, Boolean isRelativePopping)
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationParameters shellNavigationParameters, ShellNavigationRequest navigationRequest)
at TestinMAUIPageNavigationPerf.Sources.ViewModels.ItemViewModel.SelectItem()

Note that when my second page have no element inside root <ContentPage> it seems to not crashthen (well at least for the long time I tested it).
But just adding a simple <Label Text="TEST!"/> inside result in crashing again.
EDIT I simplified the code to only have a Button in MainPage that will trigger navigation, and one Label on the SelectPage. That still crash the app on same scenario (back and forth between 2 pages).
For reference and your curiosity, here a video of this uber simplified version that still crashes in the end.

In MauiProgram.cs change AddSingleton to AddTransient - minimum for the SelectPage. BTW you should add views and their viewmodels as transient or your navigation will blow up at some point

Did you try to report this on the github repo? I cloned your project and the problem alway appeared on navigation dozens of times.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes I did it here : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/24858.

You can follow up it to see if it has any update.


This is an UPDATED ANSWER. I have been able to:

Confirm the specific exception being thrown
Attribute it to builder.Services.AddSingleton<SelectPage>()
and exonerate the code.
Identify a possible MAUI platform bug that might explain it.
Intercept the exception and successfully use a retry mechanism to test on a long-running loop.

This debug output shows a successful retry at N=5 but it also unexpectedly produced a message from the MAUI platform inviting us to submit a bug. I'm on it...


Test loop to Reproduce the Bug
It's not always easy to identify the cause of spurious or seemingly random exceptions, but since the posted question includes a link to the code repo it made me want to give it a try. I took the approach of setting two Conditional Compilation Symbols in the project so that I could enable an automated ping-ponging back and forth between MainPage and SelectPage as implemented in the code below, and just let it run.

The bug was easily to reproduce by cloning the code repo and adding the SELF_TEST loop shown below, with a mean time to failure of < 10 cycles. This experiment identifies that the exception is specifically a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurring (as one might expect) on the Windows platform only.

When the line that adds SelectPage as a singleton was commented out and the SELF_TEST loop run overnight, a cycle count of >25,000 was reached without failure. (This means 0 exceptions thrown.)
If the line is reinstated, exceptions seem inevitable and usually occur in << 100 cycles.

public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    .
    .
    .
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<SelectPage>();
}


Singleton is Required, However
The final SelectPage class used for test is shown below, and enforces the singleton with a Debug.Assert if attempts are made to instantiate more than once (as would be the case if builder.Services.AddTransient<SelectPage>() were used instead). It also demonstrates how to intervene and retry for the exception that is thrown. In fact, we're going to hit paydirt with this approach as shown in the image that follows.
public partial class SelectPage : ContentPage
{
#if SELF_TEST
    private static uint _instanceCounter = 0;
    public SelectPage()
    {
        _instanceCounter++;
        Debug.Assert(_instanceCounter <= 1, "Expecting only one instance of this class.");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
        await Task.Delay(AppShell.TestInterval);
        if (App.Current?.MainPage?.Handler != null)
        {
#if WINDOWS
            retry:
            int tries = 1;
            try
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{ nameof(MainPage)}");
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
            {
                if (tries == 1)
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}");
                if (tries++ < 5)
                {
                    goto retry;
                }
                else throw new AggregateException(ex);
            }
#else
            try
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SelectPage));
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name} is unexpected on this platform.");
            }
#endif
        }
    }
#else
    public SelectPage() => InitializeComponent();
#endif
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if(MainPageViewModel.SelectedItemViewModel is ItemViewModel valid)
        {
            BindingContext = valid;
        }
    }
}


Test conditions
Here's the remainder of the test code I ended up using: Clone: windows-machine-successful-test
The biggest change is moving the SelectItemCommand to the MainPageViewModel:
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public static ItemViewModel? SelectedItemViewModel { get; set; }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task SelectItem(ItemViewModel item)
    {
        SelectedItemViewModel = item;
        try
        {
            if (App.Current?.MainPage?.Handler != null)
            {
#if WINDOWS
                retry:
                int tries = 1;
                try
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SelectPage));
                }
                catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex) 
                {
                    if(tries == 1) 
                        Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}");
                    if (tries++ < 5)
                    {
                        goto retry;
                    }
                    else throw new AggregateException(ex);
                }
#else
                try
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SelectPage));
                }
                catch(Exception ex) 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name} is unexpected on this platform.");
                }
#endif
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Fail(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public ItemViewModel[] Items { get; } = new[]
    {
        new ItemViewModel{ Title = "One" },
        new ItemViewModel{ Title = "Two" },
        new ItemViewModel{ Title = "Three" },
        new ItemViewModel{ Title = "Four" },
        new ItemViewModel{ Title = "Five" },
    };
}

In doing so, all the SelectPage needs to do is pull the current BC in the OnAppearing method (this code was already listed above). To the extent that there may have been suspicion around the original code changing the binding context synchronously within the OnNavigatedTo block, these changes were intended to perform the same bindings in a more conventional way.

The move of the SelectItemCommand is reflected the modified binding in MainPage.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestinMAUIPageNavigationPerf.Sources.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TestinMAUIPageNavigationPerf.Sources.ViewModels"
             x:Class="TestinMAUIPageNavigationPerf.Sources.Views.MainPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:MainPageViewModel">
    <!--Set BC here with x:Ref="Page"-->
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MainPageViewModel x:Name="Page"/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ScrollView>
        .
        .
        .
        <CollectionView>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:ItemViewModel">
                <Border>
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="2"
                            Command="{Binding SelectItemCommand, Source={x:Reference Page }}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                  </Border.GestureRecognizers>
              </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
          </CollectionView>
          .
          .
          .
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>


The only added functionality in the code behind for MainPage is the SELF_TEST block.
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
#if SELF_TEST
    private static uint _instanceCounter = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        _instanceCounter++;
        Debug.Assert(_instanceCounter <= 1, "Expecting only one instance of this class.");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
            await Task.Delay(AppShell.TestInterval);
            // After for optional 'long' setup interval for the first
            // iteration, followed by test at smaller increments.
            AppShell.TestInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Count = {_debugCount++}");
            var randoBC = BindingContext.Items[_rando.Next(BindingContext.Items.Length)];
            BindingContext.SelectItemCommand.Execute(randoBC);
    }
    int _debugCount = 1;
    Random _rando = new Random(Seed: 1);
#else 
    public MainPage() => InitializeComponent();
#endif
       
    new MainPageViewModel BindingContext =>(MainPageViewModel)base.BindingContext;
}

Minor Changes

Removed Singleton Registrations for MainPage, MainPageViewModel
Made all C'Tors parameterless.



I'll take time to further enquirer along your indication, but I want to thank you for your long and explained answer first.
What I can already add here is you are right I made a mistake to call Task.Delay(x).Wait() instead of await Task.Delay() corrected soon after. But ultimately I ended up few hours after to very minimal project where there is no longer BindingContext involved and no OnNavigatedTo() with just a simple Button to go to SelectPage witch display a single Label and using built in Go Back button, that still end up crashing. I'll start trying the AddTranscient.

UPDATE: I believe I found something more definitive. It's true that you don't need MainPage or MainPageViewModel as singletons, because this is a DataTemplate in the shell, but SelectPage still needs to be, right? What I think I'm seeing is a Windows-Only "Smoking Line" because if I reinstate that line, so does the NavigationFailed exception. _Changing it to AddTransient not only doesn't avert the failure (at ~10 interations of the test loop), but also makes it 'not' a singleton. I'm going to keep digging into this because it could actually be a real platform-specific bug.

Not sure to know what is a "Smoking Line". For your first note, are you referring to the fact I use compiled binding by setting x:DataType="xxxViewModel" in my <ContentPage> and <CollectionView> ? I'm note sure to know either how the Shell work behind MAUI scene and why or why not use Singleton/Transcient.

On my side I deeply tested my code and your code, altering step by step to try to emerge something causing the crash. So far what I infer is that the crash is related to how the SelectPage XAML code is done. For exemple, even after using / refactored code along yours (no Singleton, Command in MainViewModel, parameterless CTOR, testing Handle != null (I don't know exactly why and what it is tbh) ...) using a single and simple <Label> for the whole page result in crash. Using back original XAML code but limiting array number to only 5 result in crash, but 6 doesn't.

But using 6 Numbers without limiting the Border width anymore (removing MaximumWidthRequest=300, displaying the border taking whole window width, result in crash then ...

When digging in the stack trace I see the exception is throw by IFrameMethod : ExceptionHelpers.ThrowExceptionForHR(((delegate* unmanaged[Stdcall]<IntPtr, IntPtr, int>)(*(IntPtr*)((nint)(*(IntPtr*)(void*)thisPtr) + (nint)27 * (nint)sizeof(delegate* unmanaged[Stdcall]<IntPtr, IntPtr, int>))))(thisPtr, MarshalInspectable<object>.GetAbi(value))); which will throw if int argument correspond to an error code. And this argument is the result of a delegate call witch is named in code as _objRef_global__Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls_IFrame.

It's important to focus on the COMException and I agree when you made a simplified version. I did the same thing here and included a README that explains null-checking Handle and what my "smoking line" term refers to.  Finally, AddTransient will create a new instance of the object each time it is requested whereas AddSingleton will return a single/reusable instance of an object. You want the second one.

I guess my final word on this is that your question describes a COMException that "bubbles up" and causes other problems. My testing suggests that this happens in the platform when the AddSingleton is used, and that the fault doesn't lie in your code for this. You can use a retry to work around it like in my MRE. Then you might do "other things" for your app that cause "other exceptions", but these should be isolated and put into separate new questions to keep things manageable!

Thanks for your explanation in README. Didn't knew "Smoking line" expression before and your explanation is very clear with Smoking gun analogy. Handle test is now clear to me thanks. I understand the difference between AddTransient/AddSingleton. What I don't know is how it is used by MAUI framework behind, resulting in not knowing why or why not preferably use one over the other if both should/could work in theory. E.G. You mention AddSingleton is required and I don't know why.

I also agree that there seems to be several (at least 2) different exceptions occuring here.
One is the COMException that is the most obscure to me tbh. Along your finding it should revolve on bug using AddSinglon right ?
The other, NavigationFailed, is what I was focused on. It is the one I suspect to be related to the XAML code since it occur or not along how SelectPage was coded in XAML. That exception occur alone then (I mean when I eliminated any AddTransient/AddSingleton in a first place) without the COMException.

Using your pingpong code, I did two 10000 cycle long test, with and without AddSingleton. I modified the code to distinguish between COMException from MainPage and from ChildPageA.
So with AddSingleton it end up with 141 COMException from MainPage and 142 from ChildPageA. Note that during the test even if it happens one momentary take the "lead" on the other, they both rise at same pacing, resulting in equal exception throw from one and the other.
Now without AddSingleton, COMException happen only from ChildPageA. I monitored 134 of them from 10000 cycles.

So yeah removing AddSingleton resolve one part of the navigation exception (The ones called from MainPage).
The other exceptions aren't removed though in this simple XAML testing pages. I Will try with same kind of XAML that I found it didn't crash in my yesterday tests in your ChildPageA.xaml to see if COMException still happens or not.

With XAML code displaying what I displayed in my project (a grid of numbers), tested with 6 and 5 numbers. I expected no crash with 6 and some crashes with 5. But I ended up with 1 early crash with 6 numbers coded in XAML at ~300 cycles out of 10 000, and only 2 early crashes with 5 numbers coded in XAML at 25 and 49 cycles out of 10 000. So kinda no crash without singleton AND with more "complex" XAML code. I doubt XAML code is a primary culprit here, more a side effect thing i guess.

Just to notice it here since we were talking about that, I get back to my original issue meanwhile of understanding navigation performance issue. Indeed i noticed that navigating to my SelectPage took time to be generated (I suspect Datas Binding behind cause this performance drop). And now I understand why AddSingleton<SelectPage>() is required because then only the first page generation took time, and any further navigation to it is faster with this singleton page. But then we hit the bug you pinpointed to AddSingleton().

Thoughts: 1. Are you developing this in MAUI because you intend it to run on platform like Android and/or iOS? Obviously there's no COMException on Android because there's no COM in the first place, but have you looked for these other exceptions you mention? 2. Do these "other" errors persist if you temporarily disable switching the binding context?

1. I'm learning MAUI with a sample project of mine (a lottery drawer, hence the grid), my plan is to use it on Android (I don't have apple device) and windows. 2. I'm not sure the other exception are or aren't COM exception. I originally saw NavigationFailed was unhandled on debug break in generated App.g.i.cs, followed by (after continuing running the "breaked" app) a COMException witch then stopped the App. Now after NavigationFailed break, contnuing running the APP will result displaying visually SelectPage while navigated to MainPage according to Page Title (HOME).
